# Evaluate sympy polynomial with an array

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I need help with Sympy, I actually have a list of polynomials, let's say, of 2 variables **s0** and **s1**, however some polynomials are in **s0** only, some of **s1** only, some are just constants and some have both variables, example:

```
poly = [1 , s0 , s0+3*s1 , .... ]
```

I would like to evaluate any of them with the same command, let's say, **s0=2** and **s1=1**. For example to evaluate the third polynomial of the list I tried

```
s = sympy.symbols('s0:%d'2)
poly[2].subs(s,[2,0])

# s is containing (s0, s1), but this won't work at all

poly[2].eval([2,0])

# this one works only if the polynomial uses the two variables, so it will throw an error for poly[0] and poly[1]
```

The fact is that I don't know which one has which variable, I also don't know a priori how many variables are involved, this last information is an input of the function. Hence the need of using arrays and the same command for all polynomials in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict with subs:

```
In [12]: from sympy import *                                                                                                                                  

In [13]: s0, s1 = symbols('s:2')                                                                                                                              

In [14]: polys = [1 , s0 , s0+3*s1]                                                                                                                           

In [15]: [S(p).subs(values) for p in polys]                                                                                                                   
Out[15]: [1, 2, 5]
```